# Правила пунктуации - несколько случаев

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Объясните, пожалуйста, какие это правила. Я никак не могу понять.

*Подбор слов, грамматических форм и конструкций, даже звуков, не менее важен, чем предмет разговора. В художественном тексте основное творческое усилие переносится с того, что сказано, на то, как сказано. Именно в тонкой пропорции между смыслом опуса и мастерством автора, несвойственной другим видам литературы, заключается художественный текст.*

Интересуют выделенные запятые:
*Подбор слов, грамматических форм и конструкций, даже звуков(,) не менее важен(,) чем предмет разговора. В художественном тексте основное творческое усилие переносится с того, что сказано(,) на то, как сказано. Именно в тонкой пропорции между смыслом опуса и мастерством автора(,) несвойственной другим видам литературы(,) заключается художественный текст.*

Comment: Яна, посмотрите мою правку вашего вопроса, пожалуйста. Я постарался сделать его распознаваемым для других членов сообщества. если я что-то не так понял,  поправьте меня. Но не надо делать так, как у вас в исходном варианте. Ничего не понятно с первого раза.

Comment: @behemothus, Хорошо было бы пробел после запятой в "литературы,заключается".  Кроме того, что повтор вообще-то не нужен, читается нормально.

Comment: За пробел - спасибо, сейчас поправлю. А повтор - это пускай автор скажет. Дело в том, что в скобки обычно заключаются **сомнительные** запятые. А тут их надо просто выделить, сомнений в них нет, надо правило на них. Автор очень мучился, не зная, как это сделать. И я не знаю.

Comment: Я еще думаю, а правильно ли по контексту тут слитное написание "несвойственный". Я бы скорее раздельно написал. Но это другой вопрос, не хочу грузить.

Comment: Только сейчас заметил, что ответ-то уже есть ))) Мне добавить нечего.

Answer (score 2):

Подбор слов, грамматических форм и конструкций, даже звуков, НЕ МЕНЕЕ ВАЖЕН, чем предмет разговора. **Даже звуков**-присоединение,НЕ МЕНЕЕ ВАЖЕН, **чем предмет разговора** -сравнит. оборот(сравниваются подбор слов и предмет разговора)

[В художественном тексте основное творческое усилие переносится с того,(что сказаНО -придаточное мест.-определительное), НА то],( как сказано - придат. мест.-опред).

Именно в тонкой пропорции между смыслом опуса и мастерством автоРА, **несвойственной другим видам литературы,**(обособленное определение, выраженное прилагат. с завис. словами) ЗАключается художественный текст

Comment: Спасибо. Это у меня клавиатура уже стёрлась, когда замечаю, что набрала не так, когда нет.